# Is the word "breaking" in the following sentence correct?

Tags: possessives

> I always carried an extra mask on my belt, in the case of mine
>   breaking.

I thought maybe it could end in "break". Sorry if it's obvious, I'm not a native speaker.

Comment: I would say "... in case mine broke".

Comment: change tense - 'i always carry an extra mask on my belt in case my current one breaks'

Comment: @JonMarkPerry It has to be in the past tense.

Answer (score -1):

In this sentence, I'd replace everything after the comma with "in case mine were to break". Your usage is incorrect.

Answer (score -1):

It is not correct. “In the case of” sounds awkward. 
@HotLicks is right. I always carried an extra mask on my belt, in case mine broke.